# For any query on a django model, performing query only on elements that have active set as true

Tags: python, django

Due to lack of planning I found myself in a situation where I had to introduce a Boolean field called "Active" at later stage in model.The idea is to return only elements that have active as true for any query on Db. One way possible would be to edit all my queries on model to add something like

```
Q(active==true)
```

which would require a lot of change. Is it possible that using "class meta" I can set ordering so that any query on Db is only performed on elements that have active set as true.

```
class Db(models.Model):
   url = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   active = models.BooleanField()(initial=True)

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['-id']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can add new QuerySet methods for your model as this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/).

```
from django.db import models

class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)



# Using it in a model:

from django.db.models.query import QuerySet    

class Entry(models.Model):
   ...
   objects = QuerySetManager()
   ...
   class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def chckactive(self):            
            return self.filter(active=True)


#   Entry.objects.all().chckactive()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom default object manager and filter out depending upon your criteria.

Refer [Custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) , however keep in mind for this [Do not filter away any results in this type of manager subclass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#do-not-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass) as django warns for overriding default object manager.